# DotNetNuke Migration to SharePoint

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

Is there a way to migrate DNN to SharePoint? We want to move all the contents from DNN to SharePoint.

Is there any DNN API to export contents like documents, images and other files?

Also, where the file contents are stored in DNN SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why?

Are you using DNN as a document management tool (with DMX or OpenContent) only? Then it could be reasonable.

DNN and Sharepoint are completely different products, Sharepoint is a great document management and workflow tool, and DNN is a multi purpose CMS (and SharePoint is completely unusable for this).

Anyway, I don't think that there is anybody who offers a migration tool, so you have to find out yourself if you really want to do this...

And yes, there are API for a lot of things in DNN, but it depends on the extension used.

Comment: We are going to move the DNN site to SharePoint and is there any api to read file and its content in DNN server.

Comment: @NavasShereef there are potentially many APIs (or zero), but it completely depends on what version of DNN you are running, and what custom modules you have in place.

Comment: It depends on the extension you are using, and the DNN version, as Chris said. If you could give this information, you might expect an answer.